# Java doesn't read portuguese txt

Tags: java

Java doesn't recognize portuguese characters and can't thus read and edit my txt as I want it to. Basically, all I wanted was that it separated the lines that start with a specific character from the other ones. Thanks.

I tried many ways of making it read, at the end it treats the txt as if it has no lines at all.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Indice {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Resources/dedu.txt"));
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= 20000) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        char f = line.charAt(0);
        if (f == '-') {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    i++;
    }
}

}
```

It should print the lines that start with '-', instead it does nothing or shows error.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: What is the input you're trying to read but can't?

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips to debug your code

Comment: It might be encoding issue. Instead of scanner, use FileInputStream and pass encoding type as a parameter

Comment: Java has no particular sense of Portuguese or Chinese or English *characters*.  It knows about national and language *locales*, but the key thing you need to know about for reading text is the *character encoding*, a.k.a. charset.  By initializing your Scanner via the `Scanner(File)` constructor, you are relying on the file to be encoded according to the system's default charset.  If there's any chance that that is not in fact its encoding, then you should use one of the constructors that allows you to specify (and you should specify correctly, of course).

Comment: As a separate issue, note that `String line = sc.nextLine(); char f = line.charAt(0);` is risky.  If your input file contains any completely empty lines then `line.charAt(0)` will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when it hits the first of those.

Comment: as per @jpthesolver2 Java should read portuguese fine, so it sounds like there is a problem with your code. What does your txt and project directory look like?

Comment: does the code read English text?  and reading exactly 2000 lines is kind of strange; wouldn't it be better to read to the end of the file? what happens if you print all lines, without checking the first character (just for testing)?